# Thunderclient how to pass a response value to the next request

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

I want to use [thunderclient](/questions/tagged/thunderclient) to test an http api.

The steps below are all working

```
 +--------+                                         +------------------+
 |        |--1 -- Login with user + pass         -->|  Server          |
 |        |                                         |                  |
 |        |<-2 -- Login reply with access_token  ---|  if user+pass ok |
 |        |                                         |                  |
 |        |--3 -- checkConfig-request with token -->|  check token     |
 | Client |                                         |                  |
 |        |<-4 -- Reply with payload             ---|  if token ok     |
 +--------+                                         +------------------+
```

But currently i copy the value of `access_token` from step 2 into step 3 and then send the request manually.

This is the reply from step 2

```
{
  "access_token": "---best---kept---secret---",
  "expires_in": 300,
  "refresh_expires_in": 0,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "not-before-policy": 1626860494,
  "scope": ""
}
```

I want to use the value from `access_token` from the `Login`-Reply (2) pass it to a variable `{{access_token_cc}}` and then use this variable to pass the value of `access_token` as the `Bearer Token` in the `checkConfig`-request (3) (see screen)

[image: Thunderclient_how_to_pass_a_variable]

### Question - how to use a variable?

I do not quite understand how to create a variable and assign a value to it. There is a video on youtube but the step to put the pieces together is to brief and not really explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support#set-environment-variable)

Set the source of the variable to `json.access_token`

Determine which type of environment you want to store it to

Answer (score 12):

[rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) did point out from the [documentation](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support#set-environment-variable) how to "connect / wire up" a variable to a value in the reply. Because the docs do not contain any images the screenshots below hopefully help to illustrate how to set up variables.

### Example to create and assign a variable

To be able to use a variable three things must be done

1. **Create:** Create a variable as part of an environment. Switch to tab `Env`, create a New Environment. Inside it create a variable `fruitShop.next_url` and optionally assign an initial value. Set the Environment to active.
2. **Assign:** Switch to tab collection, create a new collection, add a request. For a request under the tab test the value of a response field can be assigned to a variable - see screen below `json.access_token = {{access_token_cc}}`
3. **Use:** In a request you can use a variable from your active Environment with the syntax {{yourvariable}}.

The [fruitShop-REST-API](https://www.predic8.de/post-put-patch-beispiel.htm) (german) reply returns a json structure like this

```js
{
  "meta": { "count": 32, "limit": 10, "page": 1
          ,"next_url": "/shop/products/?page=2&limit=10" }
  , "products":[ 
      { "name": "Bananas", "product_url": "/shop/products/3"}
      , { ... }]
}
```

### Create

In the screen you can see

- the environment `fruitShop`
- and some variables - for example `fruitShop.next_url` and `fruitShop.count`; both with initial values.

[image: Thunderclient create a variable]

### Assign

To assign a value to the variable  you need to switch to the tab collections

- Create a collection (here `fruitShop`) and
- Add a request (here `Get Products 1`)
- Click the request (here `Get Products 1`) and switch to the tab `test`.

[image: Thunderclient assign value to var]

With the option `Set Environment Variable` you can assign a response value to a variable.

[image: Thunderclient Request Test set environment variable]

In the screen the response fields (`json.meta.count` and  `json.meta.next_url`) are assigned to variables from your envirionment:

```js
// response field       environment variable
json.meta.count = {{fruitShop.count}}
json.meta.next_url = {{fruitShop.next_url}}
```

### Use

You can now use the variable with this syntax `{{yourVariable}}`

[image: Thunderclient use a variable]

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use it for authorization.

1. In login endpoint in the Tests tab I create test starting with json.token (name "token" from the field of the login response) then I choose "setTo" option of the test and give it a variable name eg {{token}}. I don't create any environment variables manually.
2. In the tested endpoint in the Headers tab I create the field eg Authorization and give it a value: Bearer {{token}}
3. In the backend middleware I retrieve the token with: const token= req.header('Authorization').split(" ")[1]

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches to achieving this the Scripting approach and the Filter Env variable which has been answered by @surfmuggle

Lets look at the scripting method since that's a bit simple.
Please is the problem i will end up solving.
I want to set a refresh token as an environment variable anytime send that end point to that other endpoints will be able to access it.

1. On the request you want to set the env variable, go to Tests and then to Scripting in my case *{{host}}/api/v1/sessions*

[Desired route page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/822Ca.png)

You can run your script in the Inline Script text area.
The *tc* variable is the global Thunder Client object that has a lot of methods and other properties on it. But the one we are interested in is the *setVar* method.
You can use this variable to set and delete an env variable.
First we get the response body as json object
*const json = tc.response.json;*

we can then set the env variable
tc.setVar("ACCESS_TOKEN", json.accessToken)

*"ACCESS_TOKEN"* = the env variable name and *json.accessToken* = the env value

After send the request at this endpoint the environment variable will be that's all.
[example script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjfTt.png)

Now I use it as a an env variable as follows:
[example usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4hVk.png)

you can read more on this in the official documentation [official documentation](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/filters.md#inline-scripting)